# Showing 0 first posts and 0 late answers since 2 months?

Tags: support, review

My reputation is 300+. I wanted to review the new questions and answers. Earlier it showed me to review. But presently every time whenever i check, It is showing `0 First Answers` and `0 Late Answers`. It means all reviewed or what is the issue ?

Comment: Because other users have already complete the review, so queue is empty. Now wait for new posts, keep looking at the review section regularly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Review section has following review task with the required reputation

- First Posts (You need at least 125 reputation to review First Posts.)
- Late Answers (You need at least 125 reputation to review Late Answers. )
- Suggested Edit (You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edit Posts.)
- Low Quality Posts (You need at least 2k reputation to review Low Quality Posts.)
- Close Votes (You need at least 3k reputation to review Close Votes.)
- Reopen Votes (You need at least 3k reputation to review Reopen Votes.)

As you can see that only `First Post` & `Late Answers` can be done by users who has >= 125 & <= 2K reputation. The number of users are getting increase day by day. So there are lots of users with the same privilege doing the review task for the same two sections. This is the only reason that both of those queue are empty.

You need to be very quick & regularly visit the review section for the same review tasks.

Comment: if you have more than 2k rep you can no longer review first posts or late answers?

Answer (score 4):

Because there are lots of reviewers who review all the First Answer and Late questions thats why it showing you 0 First Question and 0 Late Answer. So you need to check frequently to review First Question and Late Answers.

Answer (score 0):

First Posts and Late Answers review posts are reviewed quickly. And every time (may be 10-15 minutes) about 8-10 posts* come in review tasks. So you need to check frequently to review these posts.

<sup>* Not sure: writing from my experience.</sup>